# For Loop error in java

Tags: java, for-loop

I got an assignment in which i have to fetch `i` id and display all `j` values under that id. But I have a problem: on `i` 1st value `j` values are coming properly but on `i` 2nd id `j` same values are coming which it is showing on 1st id; it's not updating.

The code snippet is:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= assignment.getValue().size(); i++){

        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        tr.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);

        TableLayout.LayoutParams tableRowParams=
              new TableLayout.LayoutParams
              (TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

        int leftMargin=0;
        int topMargin=2;
        int rightMargin=0;
        int bottomMargin=1;

        tableRowParams.setMargins(leftMargin, topMargin, rightMargin, bottomMargin);

        tr.setLayoutParams(tableRowParams);

        value[i]= new TextView(this);
        value[i].setText(assignment.getValue().get(i));
        System.out.println(value[i].getText().toString());
        value[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tr.addView(value[i]);

   for(int j= 0; j < assignment.getScore().size()/assignment.getValue().size(); j++){
         scr[i]= new TextView(this);
             scr[i].setText(categorylist.getScore().get(j));
             System.out.println(scr[i].getText().toString());
             scr[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
             tr.addView(scr[i]);
   }  t1.addView(tr, tableRowParams);
```

Comment: Please post the *real* code, not your pseudocode.

Comment: Not enough to identify the problem

Comment: Your `j` loop doesn't act upon `i`, or anything derived from the outer loop ... hence the same output regardless of `i`.  In fact, if you moved your nested `j` loop out so it was 'stand alone', you'd get the same thing.

Comment: i updated the code please check

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> on i 1st value j values are coming properly but on i 2nd id j same values are coming which it is showing on 1st id. its not updating
```

If I understand your problem correctly you want to have j to work according to i. but if i see your code there is no relationship between i & j.

```
for(int j= 0; j < assignment.getScore().size()/assignment.getValue().size(); j++){   
 ...
 ...
}
```

For the 2nd loop to work properly, have a dependency on i (according to your logic).

Comment: @Muuna. Thanx for the reply. Yes ur correct. But i have taken the size of assignment.getValue().size() that i was taking it for i and taking values in this way scr[i].setText(categorylist.getScore().get(j));

Comment: I tried to compare with i also in many ways like for(int j= 0; j <= i; j++) but giving error array out of bound exception.

Comment: did u get where i am doing mistake??

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear what kind of relationship exists between assignment.getValue() assignment.getScore() and categoryList.getScore() .If the realtionship is established correctly you might get a better answer.

scr[i].setText(categorylist.getScore().get(j));

No matter what the 'i' is you are always setting the same categorylist.getScore().get(j) to the scr[i] ,

would something like

scr[i].setText(categorylist[i].getScore().get(j)) may be the fix for your issue